# proper way to use callback function and understanding arrow notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

In my increaseCount method I have 3 different ways of increasing the count. I thought the first method could be used twice but it doesn't work as it seems to merge the setState in the callback. What's the proper way to use a callback function and why does the arrow notation work? How is prevState.count being defined? It is never set to 0

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  increaseCount() {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count }, function() {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    });

    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });

    this.setState(prevState=>({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.increaseCount()}>Increase</button>
        </div>
        <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, only your third method is a proper way to increment a state value. Going through your attempts:

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count }, function() {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
});
```

This snippet is redundant (you set the count to the same value), then when that state change has finished, you then increment the count by adding 1 to `this.state.count`. While that's fine here, you could have just done that to begin with (as in your next snippet).

Next:

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
```

Better, but the `setState` method is asynchronous, so the actual state change won't occur until later. That means that this will work in most cases, but if you were to call it twice it *would not* increment by two, since `this.state.count` hasn't updated yet when the second call occurs.

Finally, your last attempt looks perfect:

```
this.setState(prevState=>({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
```

This uses the functional `setState` syntax where react will give your callback function the current state, and you are expected to read it and return your desired new state. Using this style, you could call it twice (or as many as you want) times, and each call would increment the count properly.

---

To address some of your other questions:

> it seems to merge the setState in the callback.

Correct. From the documentation linked below:

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

---

> What's the proper way to use a callback function and why does the arrow notation work?

The functional `setState` is a new-ish react feature. Arrow functions are nice but not required (unless you access `this` inside the callback). From their [documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function
>   rather than an object. **That function will receive the previous state
>   as the first argument**, and the props at the time the update is applied
>   as the second argument:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
>     counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
> }));
> ```
>
> We used an arrow function above, but it also works with regular functions:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
>     return {
>         counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
>     };
> });
> ```

---

> How is prevState.count being defined? It is never set to 0

It is being set to zero in the constructor. The line:

```
this.state = {
  count: 0
};
```

is what sets it initially. From that point, the current state (whatever it may be) is passed your `setState` callback function.

*Sorry for the wall, this answer got out of hand before I knew it. Hopefully that helps, LMK if I missed the point or there are more questions*

Comment: could you further explain That function will receive the previous state as the first argument?  is prevState the same as this.state?

Comment: @DCR `prevState` is whatever the state currently is at the moment the callback is executed. But its not *necessarily* the same as `this.state` at a given moment, as evidenced by the pitfall of the second attempt. However, it is *in most cases* the same as `this.state`. The issue is that `this.state` can be out of date, but you only need to worry about it when you do rapid state updates, or updates that depend on knowing the current state (such as an increment).

Comment: I'll also add that `prevState` is exactly the same as `this.state` at the moment the callback is executed, but *not* equal to what `this.state` was when you called `setState`.

Answer (score 1):

- The `increaseCount` function need to be an arrow function, since you didn't bind it.
- The `setState` is an async function, it will not execute immoderately after called. So the 2nd `setState` won't execute correctly. In general, it is better to `setState` once on a single event. [Link to doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
- `this.setState(function() {})` is valid, but I haven't seen `this.setState({ count: this.state.count }, function() {})` in anywhere in the doc.

To get expected result based on your code, this is the correct pattern:

```
increaseCount = () => {
  let countBuffer = this.state.count;
  countBuffer++;
  countBuffer++;
  countBuffer++;

  this.setState(prevState => ({ count: countBuffer }));
}
```

This should work, but it's not the preferred method, due to it requires multiple times of unnecessary rendering:

```
increaseCount = async () => {
  await this.setState(function(){ return { count: this.state.count + 1 } });
  await this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.setState(prevState=>({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
}
```

Comment: Per your third bullet, the [documentation is here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), and you can see from the function signature that `setState` accepts an optional callback as a second argument.

Comment: @CRice Thank you for pointing it out, but I've never seen any one use this. Any reasonable case when should use it?

Comment: I've never used it myself either, but, if after an update, you need to read the new state to do something else (store something into a db maybe?), the callback might be a good choice for that. But anecdotally, I know of no cases where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

you should [bind](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) your callback function in order to use 'this'

your constructor should look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

    this.increaseCount = this.increaseCount.bind(this)
  }
```

**Edit:**

and your inreaseCount function should look like:

```
increaseCount() {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState(prevState=> ({ count: prevState.count + 1 })) ;
  }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: look at the edit, i modified the increaseCount as well

Comment: this doesn't help.  where is prevState being defined?  How would you do this with an anonymous function?